# how to fix epub/mobi font size inconsistency on libra 2?

Tags: kobo

Just bought my first e-reader, a Kobo Libra 2.

I've tried various books but for reproducibility consider this scenario:

- factory-reset
- mount via usb to linux pc
- insert dummy user to `.kobo/KoboReader.sqlite`
- copy over the .epub and .mobi versions of [Flatland](https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/201)
- eject
- enable parental control

When viewing, .epub fonts are ludicrously large. .mobi fonts are slightly more sensible. Both give about 1 line when font size is set to maximum but I cannot shrink .epub to give more than about 24 lines:

| epub | mobi |
| --- | --- |
| [image: epub with smallest font] | [image: mobi with smallest font] |

Both books display perfectly legibly with fbreader on my S7.

Am I missing something obvious? I'd like to be able to make the epub fonts much smaller. I don't need as small as the 101x59 termux cli I use on my 3" wide Samsung S7 screen but something closer to the font size of an actual paperback would be nice so I'm not page-turning every couple of seconds.

Answer (score 1):

For .epub books successfuly converted with [kepubify](https://pgaskin.net/kepubify/), the font size can go much lower.

| kepub (minimum) | kepub (normal) |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image: kepub gives sensible font size] |